# Large size difference between Go and C executable

Tags: c, go

I tried Go tonight, and upon building a very simple program I noticed the file size of the executable was much larger than it would be in C.

A simple hello world program in Go is 1.5mb after being built:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

And here it is in C, which is much smaller at 4.9kb

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Why the large size difference if both are being compiled to machine code?

**Edit:** I am not asking how to reduce the size of the executable, I am asking why it's larger.

Comment: Also read: [Why is my trivial program such a large binary?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_is_my_trivial_program_such_a_large_binary).

Comment: I didn't ask how to reduce it, I asked why it's larger.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Maybe you shouldn't behave like a smarty pants and simply read the link. You'll be astonished.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg the origional comment FUZxxl left did not answer the question I asked. It seems like they've been removed.